# Colorpicker + localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

**I using this plugin**: [Bootstrap Colorpicker 2.5.2](https://farbelous.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/v2/)

My questions are:

- How to dynamically display the value of the input in div
- How to save this value to localStorage and change it dynamically when changing the input

I have tried several tutorials, but it does not want to keep working

**SOLVED!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colorpicker [documentation](https://farbelous.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/v2/) is complete. You just have to read it and try.

Here is a demo I did for you. I have to mention that it's the very first time I use this picker. I found all I needed in the documentation in minutes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#color").colorpicker()
  
  // While selecting a color... This event fires multiple times.
  .on("changeColor",function(){
    var selectedColor = $(this).colorpicker('getValue');
    console.log(selectedColor);
    $("#colorDisplay").css("background",selectedColor);
  })
  
  // When the picker is closed, keep the chosen color.
  .on("hidePicker",function(){
    var selectedColor = $(this).colorpicker('getValue');
    console.log("User finally chose "+selectedColor);
    
    // Save it to localStorage.
    // -- But it does not work in SO snippet...
    //localStorage.setItem("selectedColor",selectedColor);
    
  });
});
```

```css
#colorDisplay{
  height:6em;
  width: 6em;
}
.colorpicker{
  width:10em;
}
.colorpicker-color{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.2/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.2/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="colorDisplay"></div>
<input id="color">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've managed to resolve it by editing the script and adding additional code. Everything works, including localstorage. Your solution has helped me shorten the code and refine it, so thumb up.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="picker" name="color">
        </div>
```

JS

```
$("#picker").minicolors({
    control: 'hue',
    format: 'hex',
    defaultValue: '',
    letterCase: 'lowercase',
    position: 'bottom left',
    theme: 'bootstrap'
```

});

[image]

For More detailed Use, Please see: https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/index.html

Comment: It looks like you're using a different plugin than I said. Anyway, this is not exactly what I needed.

Comment: Definitely, but I would prefer the solution to the current one I have. By the way, you are not even telling me how to put the value of that input into div or dynamically store it in localstorage.